# Is Form G-325A no longer needed for K-1 visa I-129F fiancée petition?

Tags: usa, immigration, us-citizens, greencard, k1-visa

I'm about to petition for my fiancée using a K-1 visa I-129F form. I noticed that they used to require a G-325A form (Biographic Information) for both the petitioner and beneficiary.

However, the G-325A form is no longer listed in [the government's I-129F page](https://www.uscis.gov/i-129f), nor on [the I-129F checklist](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/m-1151.pdf?download=1).

Does this mean it's no longer required for a K-1 visa application? It appears that's the case but I just want to make sure before I mail the packet so I don't get it returned.

Comment: Where the passports photo has to be pasted in I 29F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct. The 04/10/17 edition of I-129F (the only edition that is currently accepted) does not need a G-325A. All the biographical information that used to be asked on the G-325A is now asked on the I-129F itself.